# How does redis publish work?

Tags: python, redis

Suppose that there is one redis-client which is subscribing to channel `c1` and another redis-client publishes "data" to channel `c1`.

At this point, does the data published is pending in a redis-server by when the client subscribing to "c1" get the data(by calling `pubsub.listen()` or `pubsub.get_message()`) or go directly to the client subscribing to the channel `c1` through a redis-server?

In other words, When a redis-client call `pubsub.getMessage()` or `pubsub.listen()`, does redis-client send a request to redis-server to get data or just get data from the local socket buffer?

When I read some documents it is saying that `pubsub.get_message()` use select module for a socket internally.

It seems to mean that the data subscribed already is in the client local buffer, not server.

Could you give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a client does [PUBLISH](http://redis.io/commands/publish), this command immediately pushes the message into all sockets that are interested in it. The message is not stored in redis. If a client wasn't subscribed at the time of publishing, he will never see the message.

I'm not familiar with python driver for redis, but judging from the names, I'd guess that `listen` sends a `SUBSCRIBE` command and `get_message` takes a message from the local buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Redis *pubsub* is *fire and forget*.

In other words, when a `publish` command is sent, the message is received by online subscribers, and who wasn't subscribed/listening for messages when the `publish` command was sent, won't never get these messages.